# Getting wrong value in req.params - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, request

I have simple get route in my app.js file,

```
app.get('/crm/traveller/editForm/:id/:trv_id', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>", req.params);
  crm2.crmTravellerEditForm(req, res);
});
```

as per above code i have set two params by name of "id" and "trv_id",
i have console logged req.params

```
GET /crm/traveller/editForm/1102/121 200 7582.166 ms - -
>>>>>>>>>>>>> { id: '1102', trv_id: 'AxisBanner_file_1627882199782_Capture2.PNG' }
```

so when i enter "localhost:8083/crm/traveller/editForm/1102/121", expected params were id = 1102 and trv_id = 121 but in console.log i m getting some image in req.params.trv_id

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: does `AxisBanner_file_1627882199782_Capture2.PNG` mean anything to you?

Comment: it is the profile image for id =1102 (from db)

Comment: Do you have any middleware (i.e. app.use definition) and does passportConfig.isAuthenticated indicate a middleware configuration?

Comment: i checked after removing passportConfig.isAuthenticated, still getting same issue, i am using app.use in app.js file and checked most of them

Comment: @KemalKaplan do u think problem is with any of (app.use) middleware??

Comment: I think so. I can suggest you to search for "trv_id" in the entire project and find the lines where it is possibly updated...